# HTML textarea min-width ignored when width is set

Tags: html, css, textarea

The min-width seems to be ignored, I cannot scale less than 200px;

Any workaround?

```
<textarea style='width:200px; max-width:400px; min-width:100px'>
    text
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's how it's suppose to work! The `min-width` and `max-width` properties should be used together to define a range of value for the element to resize to given the user's conditions (eg. monitor size). Explicitly giving the same element a `width` simply defeats this purpose.

See http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/min-width for more information

If you want a resizable `textarea` that grows with the amount of content the user adds you can have a look at this jQuery plugin: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/

Comment: I have a template that loads, but I want user to be able to change the size after loading...

Comment: Eh... not entirely sure what you need here, but maybe this could help? http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#textarea

Comment: How do you want the user to resize the textarea? By resizing their browser window, or by dragging a 'handle' on the bottom-right of the textarea (similar to how windows can be resized in an OS)?

Comment: The first link is generic and the second is broken. Looks like an old unsuful ad.